# Is it possible to time adjust push mail on iOS 5?

Tags: ios, email, apns

Is it possible to time adjust push mail on my iPhone? What I want is that the phone automatically adjust the push setting for some time slots a day. E.g. that it should push mail between 9-17, but after 17 it should not push mail for an account. Is there an app for that?

Comment: What is serving the mail for you?

Comment: By "push" do you mean "push and display a notification," or "push email to Mail but not display a notification?"

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder not displaying the notification is good enough for me. Is there an app for that?

Comment: @grm Oh—I was sure you were going to answer the first one... Why would you care when it gets pushed if it doesn't display a notification?

Comment: @TimothyMueller-Harder Sorry, the spellchecker corrected the last one. You are absolutely right! Maybe I should delete this question and ask more preciesly how I can turn off the notification instead?

Comment: @grm OK by me! Here's the answer, so you can do it before you make the new one and wait for me to answer it: go to Settings.app > Notifications > Mail, and set things how you want. :)

Comment: Yea but I would like to do that Automatically by time. Not manually :(

Comment: I've been wishing for this too. Inspired by the mobile notifications settings on Twitter.

Comment: This question shows the fundamental misunderstanding of what push really is. The push service is handled by Apple's servers. When it detects a new mail, the server will send out a notice to any client connected to the service. What you're talking about is fetching and that is handled locally. In that case, you talk to the server, negotiating a check for new mail. Push cannot be controlled in this way as that is outside of its intents and purpose.

Comment: @cksum I'm talking about time Restriction of the push. As you point out it's preferable to do it on the server side, but the push could also be ignored on the client site as well

Comment: Your wording is a bit off. What you are looking for is a "quiet time" where you will not be alerted to new push notifications. Simply put, you are looking to bring the "Sleep Option" over from Tweetbot for iOS to, well, global iOS. There is no current way of doing this. A jailbreak tweak would likely be possible, but none exist at this time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple app for this in the default Mail app as unfortunately there is no way for an app to change this setting. You either have to accept notifications all of the time, or manually turn them on/off in the Settings app every time you want to change them as @afragen said.

There may be other email apps that will provide this functionality, but I've not come across any.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't currently an option, but in iOS 6, Notifications will have a "Do Not Disturb" feature, so you can mute them at certain hours of the day. It won't stop your phone from receiving mail, but the alerts won't bother you.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off Notifications from the Settings > Notifications tab. Search for Mail and turn off all notification settings.

If you also want you might need to go to Settings > General > Sounds and turn off the New Mail sound.

Comment: This is also a manual procedure. Looking for something automatic.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to set your home WiFi router to disable internet access in general or for a specific device or specific service (like Mail) during certain hours. This would normally be under a Parental Controls section of the router setup.